Can -ㄹ까 Be Used for Nominalization?
I’m a bit confused about the grammar function of -ㄹ까 in this sentence:
나 친구들이랑 노래방 갈까 생각 중이야. (I’m thinking of going to karaoke with some friends.)
I know -ㄹ까 is usually used at the end of a sentence for suggestions or intentions like "Shall we...?" or "Should I...?" But in this case, it feels like it’s nominalizing the phrase "갈까" (like "the act of maybe going"), kind of like how -ㄹ지 is used to express uncertainty and nominalize a verb.
Is this interpretation correct, or am I missing something?

As you said, -지 (는지, ㄹ지) is the proper nominalization form, but -ㄹ지 might sound a little too serious for simple phrases like your example. I am not sure whether the -ㄹ까 clause is being used like a noun clause or not, but whatever it is works very well in the sentence.
-ㄹ까 has a more colloquial and immediate feel than -ㄹ지 (which seems to imply some reasoning) when used with such verbs as 생각하다, 생각 중이다 (= 생각하는 중이다), 망설이다 (hesitate) and the like.  For example, 할까 말까 망설였다 sounds more natural than 할지 말지 망설였다 in colloquial speech.
If you apply grammar logic to the phrase, you might derive it like this.

나 "친구들이랑 노래방 갈까"(,) 하고 생각 중이야. (direct quote. The comma is optional)
나 친구들이랑 노래방 갈까 하고 생각 중이야.  (indirect quote))
나 친구들이랑 노래방 갈까 생각 중이야. (further compressed)

'하고' is essentially a quote form similar to '라고', but it is preferred when you quote your own thought (잠시 포기할까 (하고) 생각했다) or when describing an exclamation or spontaneous sound (폭탄이 쾅 (하고) 터졌다).  Quote forms are not so strictly adhered to and a lot of variations exist.
I think you can make a similar case about non-strict quote forms in other languages too,  For instance, English sentences like "What do you mean you don't care?" seems to follow similar pattern as the Korean sentence, in that they both directly connect the verb and the remark or thought without any connector between them.

What do you mean by (saying) "I/You don't care"?  (direct quote)
What do you mean, (that) you don't care?  (indirect quote, with a comma to maintain clarity)
What do you mean you don't care?  (further compressed)

It appears to me both examples are cases of simplicity trumping grammar, although there might be different interpretations.
